# How to improve a class which has too many repetitive variable?

Tags: php, variables

I am building my website, this is my page controller,

```
/**
 * this file handles the retrieval and serving of page
 */ 
class controller_core 
{
    public $connection = null;
    public $page_model = null;
    public $authentication_admin = null;
    public $authentication_member = null;
    public $constant = null;

    public function __construct($connection)  
    {  
        $this->connection = $connection;
        $this->page_model = new __page_model($connection);
        $this->authentication_admin = new __authentication_admin($connection);
        $this->authentication_member = new __authentication_member($connection);
        $this->constant = new __constant_model($connection);
    } 

    public function render_page($authenticated_admin, $authenticated_member, $backbone)
    {
        # ob_start - Turn on output buffering. It lets you put output into a buffer instead of sending it directly to the client.
        # in computing, a buffer is a region of memory used to temporarily hold data while it is being moved from one place to another.
        ob_start();

        # set variable for users
        $user_primary = null;
        $user_secondary = null;
        $user_tertiary = null;
        $user_quartary = null;

        # set variable for members
        $member_primary = null;
        $member_secondary = null;
        $member_tertiary = null;

        # store the db connection object in the variable
        $connection = $this->connection;

        # determine it is a root user or a sub user from the class of authentication_admin
        $category_admin = $this->authentication_admin->get_admin_category($authenticated_admin);
        $category_member = $this->authentication_member->get_member_category($authenticated_member);

        # set either one of the user type to true
        switch($category_admin) 
        {
            case 'user_primary':
                $user_primary = true;
                break;
            case 'user_secondary':
                $user_secondary = true;
                break;
            case 'user_tertiary':
                $user_tertiary = true;
                break;
            case 'user_quartary':
                $user_quartary = true;
                break;
        }

        # set either one of the user type to true
        switch($category_member) 
        {
            case 'member_primary':
                $member_primary = true;
                break;
            case 'member_secondary':
                $member_secondary = true;
                break;
            case 'member_tertiary':
                $member_tertiary = true;
                break;  
        }

        # get the constant values from the class of constant
        $cst_value_site_title = $this->constant->get_constant('site_title')->cst_value;
        $cst_value_site_slogan = $this->constant->get_constant('site_slogan')->cst_value;
        $cst_value_meta_description = $this->constant->get_constant('meta_description')->cst_value;
        $cst_value_meta_keywords = $this->constant->get_constant('meta_keywords')->cst_value;


        # if $_REQUEST pg exists
        if(isset($_REQUEST['pg_url']))
        {
            # show the requested page
            # always send the value of $authentication_admin to the class of page:
            # if $authentication_admin has a value, you can see this page even if it is hidden
            # if $authentication_admin has a value, you can see this page only if it is published
            $page = $this->page_model->get_page($_REQUEST['pg_url'],$category_admin);
            $parent = $this->page_model->get_parent($page);

            # store the date into the variable
            $parent_id = $page->parent_id;
            $tmp_path = $page->tmp_path;

            # get the main template/ html document
            include $backbone;
            //print_r($authentication_admin);
        }
        else
        {   
            # if no special page is requested, we'll show the default page
            $page = $this->page_model->get_page(DEFAULT_PAGE,$category_admin);
            $parent = $this->page_model->get_parent($page);

            #store the date into the variable
            $parent_id = $page->parent_id;
            $tmp_path = $page->tmp_path;


            #get the main template/ html document
            include$backbone;
            #print_r($parent);
        }

        #Return the contents of the output buffer.
        return ob_get_contents();

        #Clean (erase) the output buffer and turn off output buffering.
        ob_end_clean();
    }
}
```

below is the class that extended from the parent controller class above, but you can see that I am repeating some(lots!) of variables from the parent class,

```
class controller_extended extends controller_core
    {
        function __construct($connection) 
        {
            parent::__construct($connection);
        }

        public function render_page($authenticated_admin, $authenticated_member, $backbone) 
        {
            # set variable for users
            $user_primary = null;
            $user_secondary = null;
            $user_tertiary = null;
            $user_quartary = null;

            # set variable for members
            $member_primary = null;
            $member_secondary = null;
            $member_tertiary = null;

            # store the db connection object in the variable
            $connection = $this->connection;

            # determine it is a root user or a sub user from the class of authentication_admin
            $category_admin = $this->authentication_admin->get_admin_category($authenticated_admin);
            $category_member = $this->authentication_member->get_member_category($authenticated_member);

            # if $_REQUEST tag_name exists 
            if(isset($_REQUEST['tag_name']))
            {
                # get the value from the request
                if(isset($_REQUEST['pg_url'])) $pg_url = $_REQUEST['pg_url'];
                if(isset($_REQUEST['tag_name'])) $tag_name = $_REQUEST['tag_name'];
                if(isset($_REQUEST['str_id'])) $str_id = $_REQUEST['str_id'];

                # show the requested page
                # always send the value of $authentication_admin to the class of page:
                # if $authentication_admin has a value, you can see this page even if it is hidden
                # if $authentication_admin has a value, you can see this page only if it is published
                $page = $this->page_model->get_page($pg_url,$category_admin);
                $parent = $this->page_model->get_parent($page);

                if(empty($str_id))
                {
                    # get the included template
                    switch($pg_url) 
                    {
                        case 'publications':
                            $tmp_path = 'resources_publication_subitem.php';
                            break;
                        case 'tender-opportunities':
                            $tmp_path = 'resources_tender_opportunitie_subitem.php';
                            break;
                        case 'research-topics':
                            $pg_url = $tag_name;
                            $tmp_path = 'item_content_research_topics.php';
                            break;
                        case 'videos':
                            $tmp_path = 'video_tagged.php';
                            break;
                        case 'forum':
                            $tmp_path = 'forum_subitem.php';
                            break;  
                        case 'ener-exchange':
                            $tmp_path = 'exchange_subitem.php';
                            break;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    # store the date into the variable
                    $parent_id = $page->parent_id;

                    # get the included template
                    switch($pg_url) 
                    {
                        case 'forum':
                            $tmp_path = 'item_forum.php';
                            break;  
                        case 'ener-exchange':
                            $tmp_path = 'item_exchange.php';
                            break;
                    }

                }

                # get the main template/ html document
                include $backbone;

            }
            else
            {
                parent::render_page($authenticated_admin, $authenticated_member, $backbone);
            }
        }
    }
```

How can I work around this repetitive variables? Maybe I have made the controller incorrectly?

Thanks.

**EDIT:**

sorry for not being clear. the method of `render_page` in my extended class is overriding the `render_page` method in the parent class, so I think I am not able to use `parent` keyword to get the variables that I store in the `render_page` method. what should I do with this? thanks.

Comment: MVC does not mean "My Very Code". That disaster there is **completely unrelated** to MVC architectural pattern.

Comment: @tereško Why the hostile tone?  I agree the question here is uninformed/misinformed, but it's possible the OP was just trying to understand a larger pattern common to frameworks as best they could.  Such attitudes are not constructive.

Comment: @DeaconDesperado see the user's profile. That should explain the hostility.

Comment: @tereško I looked and I must be missing something, care to explain?

Answer (score -1):

Its hard to get an idea for what some of these variables are intended to accomplish in deployment, but just from looking at what's here there are a few things you could consider.

You could put the switch for determining user level in a protected method of the parent class.  That way, the logic for checking what level the user is could be called by render_page in any of the descendant controllers.  You could pass in the value from get_admin_category and return a string so that switch statement could be made reusable.

Also, what is the intention behind output buffering in your example?  I see you are including an your template last at `include $backbone` but for what reason are you doing buffering?  In most released MVCs, the controller does some preprocessing, calls model methods and arranges data and then just passes it off to the view which is the only thing rendered to the client (I know CodeIgniter, for example, accomplishes this by handing off an 'output' array to the view that can contain values for output via echoing etc.).  There shouldn't be any need to delay output to the client, since in most MVCs this only occurs once the view is loaded.

From the appearance of your use of the $_REQUEST superglobal, you are relying on this to perform routing of requests to actual scripts on the server (I may be mistaken in this, just trying to interpret from what's given.)  Many MVCs will also utilize mod_rewrite() to perform all routing to one point of entry (a Front Controller) and then rely on the script to handle all the routing by calling up child constructors off the paths in the url.  This is a wonderful tutorial for exercise, not deployment, purposes:
http://www.phpaddiction.com/tags/axial/url-routing-with-php-part-one/

If you're doing this as an exercise in understanding the Front Controller pattern, there are a lot of great frameworks out there you could look at and learn some tricks from.  CodeIgniter and Kohanna are great, relatively lightweight ones that make it easy to have a look under the hood.  Obviously Zend is hugely popular as well.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am not sure about buffering - I thought it could make the site to be loaded faster - I think I should just get rid of it! thanks!

Comment: @lauthiamkok I added a link to a good tutorial on mod_rewrite routing.

Comment: Downvotes without comments make me sad.  I realize OP asked about patterns internal to frameworks, which tend to be unpopular here, but why the zombie downvote 3 years after the fact?